# How boolean treat to negative integers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer, boolean

If I am changing -1 or -2 to BOOL values, what will it return? I exactly wanted to know, how it behave with negative integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything except `0`,`0.0`,`'\0'` or `null` would return `True`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Please remove the *'*  from your answer, because it is misleading. Beside this, '\0', 0.0 will be false, too.